# How can I make expandable panels without using JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

My question is how can I create expandable panels in an HTML form without using javascript, so that when a user clicks on each panel it expands and displays the form.

Before click:

```
<ul>
    <li id="panel1"><a></a><div class="content"></div></li>
    <li id="panel2"><a></a><div class="content"></div></li>
    <li id="panel3"><a></a><div class="content"></div></li>
</ul>
```

After click:

```
<ul>
    <li id="panel1">
      <a></a>
        <div class="content">
            <form id="FORM"> ..... </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="panel2"><a></a><div class="content"></div></li>
    <li id="panel3"><a></a><div class="content"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could probably do some advanced CSS stuff to show and hide something, but how do you expect to insert a form into the HTML without using javascript (you could of course just reload the page).

Comment: jquery/ajax can serve this best

Comment: @NewBee Care to explain how they can use jQuery when no JS is a requirement?

Comment: page should work with javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using :target css pseudo selector - it is not very elegant though, as clicking on the anchor tag modifies the url so it is hard to toggle the form. Best use javascript.

```
        <style>
        form {
            display: none;
        }
        form:target {
                display: block;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
        <ul>
<li id="panel1" ><div class="content"><a href="#form">Show form</a><form id="form" > My form <input type="text"></form></div></li>
<li id="panel2"><div class="content">My content</div></li>
<li id="panel3"><div class="content">My content</div></li>
</ul>
```

some examples of :target in action:
http://css-tricks.com/css-target-for-off-screen-designs/ and http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: form should be added to html document after user click on <a> tag.

Comment: Well you cannot modify DOM with just CSS, need javascript for that

Comment: If you are doing it server side simply reload the page with new content inserted...

Answer (score 0):

Without using ANY javascript at all, you can't.

Unless you just put links and redirect your users to a page with the expanded content every time.

Or unless you write some kind of complex CSS using the :hover pseudo-selector and not the click event.

Answer (score 0):

CSS 3 has a `:target` pseudo-selector that might help. Here is an example: https://tinker.io/1756b

Comment: Ok seams nice, but how insert form without js?

Comment: This is just for toggling visibility of the panels. The content should already be populated.